# Finally clause with Daemon thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, finally

I tried this with Visual Studios 2019

```
import threading, time

def thread_func():
    try:
        print('thread start')
        time.sleep(4)
    finally:
        print('thread finish')


print('main start')
t=threading.Thread(target=thread_func,daemon=True)
t.start()
time.sleep(2)
print('main finish')
```

outputs

```
main start
thread start
main finish
```

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-try-stmt) states that the finally clause always executes, so is this non-compliance or some weird exception to the rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent process is finishing before your thread can finish executing.  That's why it never gets to the "thread finish" piece.

You can use join() to tell your process to wait for all threads to finish executing before terminating.

```
import threading, time

def thread_func():
    try:
        print('thread start')
        time.sleep(4)
    finally:
        print('thread finish')


print('main start')
t=threading.Thread(target=thread_func,daemon=True)
t.start()
time.sleep(2)
t.join()                 # Wait for threads to finish their work
print('main finish')
```

Comment: so is this standard behaviour?

Comment: Correct.  Threads are tied processes.  If a thread's parent process terminates, the thread goes with it.

You are correct in that a "finally" block always executes... as long as the thread/process is actually still running to execute it.  :)